# Excel and DB2 connectivity

Tags: vba, batch-file, excel, db2

I have to check whether the connection between Excel and DB2 has been established using CLI/ODBC driver or not.

For that I plan to write a batch file where I will be calling the excel sheet which in turn will automatically execute a macro which will bring out some dummy data from the sysibm.sysdummy1 table.

I require code with which I can make a connection to my database and check if the connection has been established or not by giving out some success message if the connection was established and a failure message if the connection was not established. (Probably with some explanation where the problem occurred)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an ODBC (or OleDB) connection between a DB2 server and Excel using ADODB (ActiveX Data Objects).  See [this link](http://connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2) for sample connection strings.

This link will show you sample VBA code to use with ADODB to connect to your database:
[How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)

**EDIT**: Here's some quick and dirty sample code.  Replace the `.connectionstring =` portion with the proper connection string for your setup.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY"
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & App.Path & _
"\ExcelSrc.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With

rs.Open strSQL, cn

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: hi banjoe , thanks for a quick response, but i need some clarification on the same. 

firstly , this is the code for VBA file which i need to call from the batch file ?

secondly , in the place of data source what to i have to put as i have already defined an ODBC datasource from the control panel.

thanks again in advance for the help ....

Comment: Try: `.ConnectionString = "DSN=yourDSNNameHere;UID=yourUserID;PWD=yourPassword;`

Comment: The code goes into a VBA module.  You can put it into the Workbook_Open event in Excel if you'd like.  Note that you'll need a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library", where X.X is the latest version available to you (6.0 in Office 2007 and beyond).  You can do this by going to Tools -> References in the Visual Basic Editor (Press Alt-F11 in Excel to bring this up).

Comment: In case this helps anyone, in my case, I had to remove `.Provider = ...` and the working connection string was: `driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};system=...;database=...;UID=...;PWD=...`